# Application crashes on device - works perfectly on Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, null, ios-simulator

Recently, I have been working on an application. The goal of the application is to show you your last 10 photos taken in the Today view of the Notification Center, among other things. The application works perfectly in the iOS Simulator, but as soon as I put it on a real device for testing, it fails. It returns the error:

```
fatal error: Unexpected nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Typically this is very easy to fix since XCode highlights the code that returned nil and gives you the opportunity to fix it. In this case, none of my code gets highlighted. Instead, it highlights a line from Thread 1 (Is this the correct term? Thread 1?), as seen below:
[image]
Also note that above the highlited line is the line

```
; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
```

I included this line in the picture because of the "fatalErrorMessage" part of it. I suspect this could clue me in on the error, but I have no idea what this means. I'm not yet to the point of understanding that.

Also, after some thought, I placed a breakpoint at the viewDidLoad() function in the hopes of tracking any nil values, but the code appears to never even get to this point. It seems as if none of my code is being run.

Has anyone had problems like this/understands what that error code (If that's what it is) means? I'm pretty desperate now, hence me being here.

Thanks,
CodeIt

**EDIT:**
I placed a println line inside the viewDidLoad function to double check if it was being run. The println function runs and outputs correctly, so I think I may just have messed up my breakpoint somehow. Anyway - the code runs, but it still doesn't highlight any of my code causing the nil value.

**EDIT 2:**
As requested, I have inserted parts of my code. Please keep in mind that this code is a "first draft", if you will, and I have not yet gotten around to cleaning it up. I'm just trying to get it to work:

```
@IBOutlet weak var currentPosLabel: UILabel!
var currentImgPos = 0
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var images: NSMutableArray!
var totalImageCountNeeded: Int!

func fetchPhotos() {
    images = NSMutableArray()
    totalImageCountNeeded = 10
    self.fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd(0)
}


func fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd(index: Int) {
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()

    var requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.synchronous = true

    var fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

    if let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions) {
        if fetchResult.count > 0 {
            imgManager.requestImageForAsset(fetchResult.objectAtIndex(fetchResult.count - 1 - index) as? PHAsset, targetSize: view.frame.size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (image, _) in
                self.images.addObject(image)
                if index + 1 < fetchResult.count && self.images.count < self.totalImageCountNeeded {
                    self.fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd(index + 1)
                } else {
                    println("Completed array: \(self.images)")
                }



            })
        }
    }

}







override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // NOTE: I am calling the fetchPhotos() function here since earlier in my debugging I thought the problem may be that I was calling it too early in the viewDidLoad function. It an incorrect theory, but it was worth a try.
    fetchPhotos()
    if images.count > 0 {
        imageView.image = images[1] as? UIImage
    }
}
```

I removed some parts of the code that I know have no reasons to cause my error, such as @IBActions, didReceiveMemoryWarning(), etc..

Comment: Just to be clear, you have set an Exception breakpoint?

Comment: @Allan Chau, Originally I just click on the side bar by a line of code to add a breakpoint. Is this an exception breakpoint? I don't think so, but I'm not sure. I'm not all that familiar with the different types of breakpoints. I have just tried adding an exception breakpoint set to All Exceptions, but it stops at the same area.

Comment: Did you find any solution for it  ?? Even I am facing the same problem..!!

Comment: @IrshadQureshi (This is a rather late reply to your question. Apologies!) The accepted answer is the answer that *might* have fixed my problem. However, I did the steps seen in the accepted answer after the Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.1 update. Anything could have changed with XCode in this update, so I'm not sure if the accepted answer really fixed the problem. It is, however, the most likely answer. I suggest trying it out and then letting us know how it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even it's old question. I found my issue by deleting derived data from xcode.

Xcode -> window->Projects then select and delete your project derived data.

Comment: was that the only thing that solved the error ? I'm having the same issue as well

Comment: I dug up the project and updated it from Swift 1 to Swift 2.1. When I ran it on my device, it no longer had the error. Any number of things could have changed when I updated it from Swift 1 to Swift 2.1, but before running it on my device, I had tried what you suggested. I'm going to accept your answer because it may have been what fixed it (Although I'll never know if it was the answer or if it was something else).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to determine exactly where the problem is without seeing your code.

Somewhere in your code you may have forced downcast a variable `as!`. If you change this to:

```
if let variable = optionalVariable as? SomeClass {
    //Insert your code
}
```

Then this should fix your problem. Read this to learn more about casting in swift:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html

Comment: I have gone through and replaced my "as!" with "as?", but it still is not fixing the problem. Thank you for the link - I will take a look and learn about proper casting! Also, I have updated the question to include code that I think is relevant to answer this question. It's currently pretty messy.

Comment: have you put code in your app delegate? I think the problem is happening before this view controller calls viewDidLoad. Perhaps check the currentPosLabel or imageView link in your storyboard.

Comment: I have no excess code in my AppDelegate, and I have double checked all the links in my storyboard items. All IBOutlets/IBActions are correctly connected. If these was a problem with the connections I would expect it to show up when ran on the Simulator. The only other thing I could think of causing a problem is that I use App Groups and NSUserDefaults to pass data between the extension and main app, however these are only ever called when a "share" button is pressed.

Comment: So, remember in my main post I said: "I placed a breakpoint at the viewDidLoad() function in the hopes of tracking any nil values, but the code appears to never even get to this point. It seems as if none of my code is being run." I just ran the code in the simulator (where it works) with breakpoints, and none of my breakpoints were tripped there either. My breakpoints are obviously not working correctly, so I'll do some investigation on the issue. Then perhaps I can track down my stray nil value.. Now, to find out why they aren't working...

Answer (score 1):

You should run the same device on simulator and real device.As an example if you run on 5s on real device then try the same device on simulator.By running simulator, it will definitely show the error.My error was the not connecting the @IBActions. Hope that this tip will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when trying to set a non-optional value to the value of an implicitly-unwrapped optional that was `nil`.

Ex. `someGlobalFunction()` returns an `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` with a nil value then you try to set that to a regular value.

```
func someGlobalFunction() -> String! { return nil }

class MyClass {
    let aVariable: String

    init() {
        aVariable = someGlobalFunction()
    }
}
```